# How can I display normals in Blender 2.8+?

Tags: normals, shortcut

How can I see the normals, because in previous versions it was in the sidebar that pops up when you press <kbd>N</kbd>. Where is it in Blender 2.8+ and is there a shortcut key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When in Edit Mode - Expand your Viewport Overlays menu at the top right, than at the very bottom you will find buttons to enable Normals overlays.
[image]

Comment: I don't get that part of the menu [a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qcr5.jpg)

Comment: You are in Object Mode, you HAVE to be in Edit Mode to view normals. Press TAB and try again.

Answer (score 3):

### Update for Blender 4.x

The version 4.0 of Blender introduced a new menu for the *Edit Mode* overlays.

So, like the previous versions of Blender, you go to *Edit Mode* on your object (by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and then look for the *Mesh Edit Mode* menu, with this icon:

[image: Mesh Edit Mode button]

In that menu, you will find the *Normals* option, which you can enable to show the normals for your faces.

[image: Mesh Edit Mode submenu]